# How can I correct a Free Fillable Forms reported error?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, online-tools, free-file-fillable-forms

I attempted to file my U.S. Federal taxes via Free Fillable Forms, and got a rejection for the following reasons:

```
Field/Xpath: /efile:Return[1]/efile:ReturnData[1]/efile:WagesNotShownSchedule[1]/efile:WagesNotShownSch[1]/efile:WagesNotShownAmt[1]
Issue      : Business Rule X0000-005 - The XML data has failed schema validation.


Field/Xpath: /efile:Return[1]/efile:ReturnHeader[1]/efile:SelfSelectPIN[1]/efile:PrimaryPriorYearPIN[1]
Issue      : Business Rule X0000-005 - The XML data has failed schema validation.
```

Now how can I correct these? I entered the numbers from the paperwork, rounded down as per prior years, and I noticed that dollar and cent amounts were rounded to the nearest dollar rather than simply down. And I need to know how to retrieve or create an appropriate PIN for federal tax returns.

I also find the error messages disappointing; I expect to need to see error messages, and I'm familiar with XML as a software developer, but to a usability person the English translation of "Business Rule X0000-005 - The XML data has failed schema validation." is "We don't know how to appropriately communicate with the general public."

So what have I run aground on? For the first issue, do I need to re-enter my wages in dollars and cents? And for the second one, how can I retrieve, create, etc. a working PIN?

--EDIT--

The PIN issue is now resolved, partly thanks to @Eric's suggestion. However, after going through and checking and correcting my W2 information, I still get:

```
Field/Xpath: /efile:Return[1]/efile:ReturnData[1]/efile:WagesNotShownSchedule[1]/efile:WagesNotShownSch[1]/efile:WagesNotShownAmt[1]
Issue      : Business Rule X0000-005 - The XML data has failed schema validation.
```

Also, when I am on the main screen (1040), the "Do the Math" button is active but the "Done with this form" button is inactive, and nothing I do seems to seems to make it active.

Advice?

Comment: There is something I forgot to mention about the first issue. I have more than one W2, and in addition I have more than one 1099-MISC form as an author, and I'm not sure I found the proper way to report 1099-MISC income. How can I properly report 1099-MISC income via Free Fillable Forms?

Comment: it should probably go to schedule C

Comment: > to a usability person the English translation of "Business Rule X0000-005 - The XML data has failed schema validation." is "We don't know how to appropriately communicate with the general public."

That is a truly excellent quote - I'm writing that down. (I'm a software guy.) :D

Answer (score 4):

I received the same error message and was able to resolve the issue by checking line 7 of my 1040 form( where the total income from wages,tips,etc as stated on the W-2) and deleting the quantity I had placed in either of the gray boxes. If you wrote the sum of your income on the doted lines in either of the gray areas of line 7 (or other such areas on other lines) then this error might result. The grey areas as I understand it, are reserved for certain descriptors which are defined in the 1040 instructions included with the free file fillable form 1040.

Comment: That was exactly my problem and the fix worked, thanks. Would it kill them to tell us the line number?

Comment: I just confirmed that line 7 was the polemic for me!

Comment: What exactly are you saying to do? Just leave line 7 blank?

Comment: Starting with 2018 taxes, the field now corresponds to `line 1`. Leave the grey box blank and only enter the wages in the white box to resolve this error.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a PIN to file electronically at the link below:

http://www.irs.gov/Individuals/Electronic-Filing-PIN-Request

Perhaps for the first issue, are all boxes and lines filled out correct? Did you correctly add your W2?

Comment: Please see comments above. How can I properly report 1099-MISC income?